# AFNetworking background downloading automatically stop after some time, I need to resume it

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using AFNetwork (its base on NAFDownloadRequestOperation) and my task in downloading multiple zip files one by one from amazon bucket.
When app is in foreground every thing is working very well, but when app goes in background mode that time downloading is running for some time only and it will automatically stop. I read some blog about it in that I get that following method called before downloading will stop.

```
 [self.operationUpdate setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                NSLog(@"downloading will stop");
            }];
```

- **Problem** in background mode downloading is automatically stop
- **What I want**: If downloading is stop in background and when app again comes to foreground I need to resume downloading from that point.

I also use following code in AppDelegate but I am not understand how to resume previous downloading.

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
        [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"applicationWillResignActive");

        [__SERVER_INSTANCE cancellAllDownloading];

     //   [[YourRestClient sharedClient] cancelAllHTTPOperations];
    }];
```

If any one have any solution please let me know, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [AFDownloadRequestOperation](https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation)

Your request will look like

```
AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request targetPath:path shouldResume:YES];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operations addObject:operation];
```

After you restart your app, and generate the request having a same url, it will resume downloading. "shouldResume:YES" works.

So, on your background task you can recreate request to finish download

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
        [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"applicationWillResignActive");

        [__SERVER_INSTANCE cancellAllDownloading];

     //   recreate here your request to finish fownload, 
     //or recreate in when app will enter foreground
    }];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: recreate here your request to finish fownload ?
means here I need to cancel downloading right ?

Comment: you have about 10 minutes for performing operations in background. if you know, that request will finish before this time - you can resume downloading.  otherwise, call operations.suspendAll to pause, and when you will enter foreground, make AFDownloadRequestOperation with the same params - it will resume downloading

Comment: before downloading stop control come in  setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler this method. how I can pause here because I try to pause downloading in this method but it can't paused.

Comment: AFJSONRPCClient has property operationQueue. call sunspendAll to stop all operations

Comment: you could create your own downloadQueue and make your apiClient as singleton, so you can access it everywhere you need

Answer (score 0):

The background downloading stops because after sometime because you might not have enable Background Fetch in Capabilities in xcode.

Please see attached screenshot[image]

And Appdelegate You have write this code,

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
    return true;
}
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
 completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

OR

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];



        NSTimeInterval ti = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]backgroundTimeRemaining];
        NSLog(@"backgroundTimeRemaining: %f", ti);

        // just for debug
    }];
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: I have enable background fetch option, but not used following two method, what they are doing exactly

Comment: till issue is there :(